# How would I use values from two different functions where their keys match?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having troubles trying to use the values from each function and combine them together. I have local variables from each function that I would like to use to in a different function where I would divided each value as long as their primary (categories) match each other. I currently have:

```
counters = {}

def participated():
    for line in reader:
        if int(line[6]) > 0:
            primary = line[7].strip('[]')
            counters.setdefault(primary, 0)
            counters[primary] += 1

    for k, v in counters.items():
        print(k, v)

def generalNumber():
    for line in reader:
        primary = line[7].strip('[]')
        counters.setdefault(primary, 0)
        counters[primary] += 1

    for k, v in counters.items():
        print(k, v)
```

How would I go about and taking the `v` from `counter.item()` from each function and using it to divide each other such as:

```
success_percentage = v from participated() / v from generalNumber ()
```

where

```
participated().primary = generalNumber().primary
```

Comment: Instead of printing the values just `return counters` and use those dictionaries to do the other stuff in a loop.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you expand more on how I can use     return counters    and use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `counter` dict local to each function, and `return` each `counter` in your functions:

```
def participated():
    counters = {}
    for line in reader:
        if int(line[6]) > 0:
            primary = line[7].strip('[]')
            counters.setdefault(primary, 0)
            counters[primary] += 1

    for k, v in counters.items():
        print(k, v)
    return counter

def generalNumber():
    counters = {}
    for line in reader:
        primary = line[7].strip('[]')
        counters.setdefault(primary, 0)
        counters[primary] += 1

    for k, v in counters.items():
        print(k, v)
    return counter
```

---

Then call the functions and perform your division with the returned dictionaries, like so:

```
counter_p = participated()
counter_g = generalNumber()

# here you have a list of success percentages
success_percentage = [counter_p.get(primary)/counter_g.get(primary, 1) for primary in counter_p]
```

---

I have used `get` with a default `1` in `counter_g.get(primary, 1)` so that if `primary` exists in `counter_p` but not in `counter_g`, the code does not break, but silently returns `1`.